# Duplicate a form to work independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which is currently doing a simple calculation. I have a button to duplicate the same form with an increment id and I need to do the calculations of the forms added independently.

```js
var myJson = {
  "platforms": [{
      "name": "Sitecore",
      "id": "Sitecore",
      "tasktype": [{
          "name": "Promobox",
          "id": "Promobox",
          "components": [{
              "name": "Box 0",
              "id": "box0",
              "time": "20"
            },
            {
              "name": "Box 1",
              "id": "box1",
              "time": "30"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Video",
          "id": "Video",
          "components": [{
              "name": "Box 2",
              "id": "box2",
              "time": "25"
            },
            {
              "name": "Box 3",
              "id": "box3",
              "time": "30"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Siab",
      "id": "Siab",
      "tasktype": [{
          "name": "Newswire",
          "id": "Newswire",
          "components": [{
              "name": "Box 4",
              "id": "box5",
              "time": "50"
            },
            {
              "name": "Box 5",
              "id": "box5",
              "time": "40"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Task Type New",
          "id": "Task Type New",
          "components": [{
              "name": "Box 6",
              "id": "box6",
              "time": "20"
            },
            {
              "name": "Box 7",
              "id": "box7",
              "time": "100"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};



$.each(myJson.platforms, function(index, value) {
  var platform_id;
  var tasktype_id;
  var component_id;

  $("#platform").append('<option rel="' + index + '" value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');

  $("#platform").change(function() {
    $("#tasktype, #component").find("option:gt(0)").remove();
    $("#tasktype").find("option:first").text("Loading...");

    platform_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');

    $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype, function(index1, value1) {
      $("#tasktype").find("option:first").text("Select Task Type");
      $("#tasktype").append('<option rel="' + index1 + '" value="' + value1.id + '">' + value1.name + '</option>');
    });

  });


  $("#tasktype").change(function() {
    $("#component").find("option:gt(0)").remove();
    $("#component").find("option:first").text("Loading...");

    tasktype_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');

    $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype[tasktype_id].components, function(index2, value2) {
      $("#component").find("option:first").text("Select Component");
      $("#component").append('<option rel="' + index2 + '" value="' + value2.time + '">' + value2.name + '</option>');
    });


  });


});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calculate').click(function() {
    let tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo("#data tbody");
    $('#calc input, #calc select').each(function(index) {
      var input = $(this);
      $(tr).append('<td class=row-' + $(input).attr("id") + '>' + $(input).val() + '</td>');
    });

    const componentFactor = $(tr).children(".row-component").text();
    const units = $(tr).children(".row-units").text();
    const total = componentFactor * units;

    $(tr).append('<td>' + total + '</td>');
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  var calc_index = 0;
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    calc_index++;
    $("#calc").after($("#calc").clone().attr("id", "calc" + calc_index));
    $("#calc" + calc_index).css("display", "inline");
    $("#calc" + calc_index + " :input").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + calc_index);
      $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + calc_index);
    });

  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calculate').click(function() {
    let tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo("#data tbody");
    $('#calc1 input, #calc1 select').each(function(index) {
      var input = $(this);
      $(tr).append('<td class=row-' + $(input).attr("id") + '>' + $(input).val() + '</td>');
    });

    const componentFactor = $(tr).children(".row-component").text();
    const units = $(tr).children(".row-units").text();
    const total = componentFactor * units;

    $(tr).append('<td>' + total + '</td>');
  });
});


$("#clear").click(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Production Units Calculator</h2>

<div class="formset">
  <form id="calc">
    <label>Platform:</label>
    <select id="platform" name="platform">
      <option value="0">Select Platform</option>
    </select>
    <label>Task Type:</label>
    <select id="tasktype" name="tasktype">
      <option value="0">Select Task Type</option>
    </select>
    <label>Component:</label>
    <select id="component" name="component">
      <option value="0">Select Component</option>
    </select>
    <label>Units:</label>
    <input name="units" id="units" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Input Units" />
    <br />
  </form>
</div>

<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<button id="addNew">Add New</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>


<table style="width:50%" id="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Platform</th>
      <th>Task Type</th>
      <th>Component</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

I was able to duplicate form with an increment ID however once the form is duplicated by clicking on **add new** , duplicated form doesn't work as the first one.

Comment: Please explain `duplicated form doesn't work as the first one`

Comment: Both seem to work the same in your snippet. What doesn't the new form do that it should be doing?

Comment: Populate the first set of form fields and then click on add new button. This will duplicate the same form. then try to populate the second form it doesn't work correctly. as in essentially how the form must work is once you select a option from the platform dropdown, Task type dropdown must be populate accordingly followed by the third.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/arzg9mz3/7/)
You need to consider the change event for duplicate ID too.

```
 $("#addNew").click(function() {
         calc_index++;
         $("#calc").after($("#calc").clone().attr("id", "calc" + calc_index));
         $("#calc" + calc_index).css("display", "inline");
         $("#calc" + calc_index + " :input").each(function() {
             $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + calc_index);
             $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + calc_index);
         });


         //TODO
         $.each(myJson.platforms, function(index, value) {
             var platform_id;
             var tasktype_id;
             var component_id;

             pID = "#platform" + calc_index;
             tID = "#tasktype" + calc_index;
             cID = "#component" + calc_index;

             $(pID).append('<option rel="' + index + '" value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
             $(pID).change(function() {
                 $(tID, cID).find("option:gt(0)").remove();
                 $(tID).find("option:first").text("Loading...");

                 platform_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');
                 $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype, function(index1, value1) {
                     $(tID).find("option:first").text("Select Task Type");
                     $(tID).append('<option rel="' + index1 + '" value="' + value1.id + '">' + value1.name + '</option>');
                 });

             });


             $(tID).change(function() {
                 $(cID).find("option:gt(0)").remove();
                 $(cID).find("option:first").text("Loading...");

                 tasktype_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');

                 $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype[tasktype_id].components, function(index2, value2) {
                     $(cID).find("option:first").text("Select Component");
                     $(cID).append('<option rel="' + index2 + '" value="' + value2.time + '">' + value2.name + '</option>');
                 });


             });


         });
```

Comment: This is basically what I needed but there's an issue when you populate the first set of fields and then add another form, second set of dropdowns has values duplicated.

Comment: You can improve your code by using function / method. Any how you need to remove the existing options before duplicating the form , simply needs to reset. Please check this fiddle, I have updated it.